# React search (filter) function, add parameter to search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

****EDIT****: shouldnt be as easy as add: `client.clientno.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1 || client.id === filter`? in the  `submitFilter` function? The problem here is that I get an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null
(anonymous function)

Im trying to edit a filter search function I've got, but Im not understanding where to add the new parameter to search or if I should deconstruct the object "client" to search more specifically. Right now I can only search by `client.text` (which is the client name) but I want also be able to search by `clientno` (client number), which is not a number but a string that looks like this: "C123456". Can someone explain where should i add my `client.clientno`parameter and how can I filter by that parameter without loosing the filter by client.text?

my code with the "search filter": (THank you very much in advance to any help!)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Form, FormGroup, Input} from 'reactstrap';
import {StatusList} from './ClientList';
import {FormattedMessage, injectIntl} from 'react-intl';

class _SearchClientsContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.timer = null;

    this.state = {
      filter: null,
      clients: this.props.clients,
    };
  }

  changeFilter = event => {
    event.persist();
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    this.setState({filter: event.target.value});
    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.submitFilter(event);
    }, 200);
  };


   submitFilter = event => { //<---------- my submit filter "search" function
     event.preventDefault();
     const filter = this.state.filter ? this.state.filter.toLowerCase() : '';
    const clients = filter.length === 0 ? this.props.clients : this.props.clients.filter(client => {
  return (


        client.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1 || client.id === filter
 // <----- here I return the client.text and I need to filter by client.clientno as well which is a string that looks like this: C123456


      );
    });
    this.setState({clients});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <h3 className="mb-3">
             <FormattedMessage id="header.navbar.clientlist.title" />
          </h3>
           <Form className="mb-4" onSubmit={this.submitFilter}>
            <FormGroup>
               <Input
                 type="text"
                 placeholder={this.props.intl.formatMessage({id: 'header.navbar.clientlist.filter'})}
                 onChange={this.changeFilter}
               />
             </FormGroup>
           </Form>
         </div>
        <StatusList clients={this.state.clients} />
      </>
     );
    }
 }

 export const SearchClientsContainer = injectIntl(_SearchClientsContainer);
```

I forgot to mention, this is how I display the list:

```
import React, {memo} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {FormattedMessage} from 'react-intl';

const StatusItem = ({client}) => {
  return (
    <p className="mb-2 cursor-pointer" onClick={() => (window.location.href = client.viewLink)}>
      <strong>{client.text}</strong> {client.clientno && <span>({client.clientno})</span>}
    </p>
  );
};

StatusItem.propTypes = {
  client: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const _StatusList = ({clients}) => {
  const favClients = clients.filter(c => c.favorite);
  const normalClients = clients.filter(c => !c.favorite);
  return (
    <div>
      <h3 className="mb-3">
        <FormattedMessage id="header.navbar.clientlist.favourites" />
      </h3>
      <div className="mb-4">
        {favClients.map(c => (
          <StatusItem client={c} key={c.id} />
        ))}
      </div>

      <h3 className="mb-3">
        <FormattedMessage id="header.navbar.clientlist.clients" />
      </h3>
      <div>
        {normalClients.map(c => (
           <StatusItem client={c} key={c.id} />
        ))}
       </div>
     </div>
   );
 };

 _StatusList.propTypes = {
   clients: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
 };

 export const StatusList = memo(_StatusList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null (anonymous function)`

```js
(client && client.toLowerCase().clientno ? client.clientno : '').toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1 || client.id === filter
```

Also you can filter like this

```
this.props.clients.filter(client => {
  return (
        client.text.toLowerCase().includes(filter)
        || client.clientno.toLowerCase().includes(filter)
        || client.id === filter
      );
});
```

Comment: woow this is amazing!!! Im now able to filter by clientno (but no by client.text at the same time) :p anyway I am a lot closer thanks to you!!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: it works perfect!! I made a little change cause the second code didnt work so well, but this did (same as you wrote + my old code)         client.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1 || client.id === filter || (client && client.clientno || client && client.text ? client.clientno || client.text : '').toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1 || client.id === filter

Comment: @FernandoLöpez Nice!!! why did you write `client.id === filter` two time ? its Redundant code please check and remove second `client.id === filter` if not needed